# Query with `embeds_many`

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I'm working with a code that has an `embeds_many` like this:

```
defmodule People do
 (...)
  schema "people" do
    embeds_many :addresses, Address
  end
  (...)
end

defmodule Address do
  (...)
  @primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: false}
  embedded_schema do
    field :type, :string
  end
  (...)
end
```

A typical value for addresses would be:

```
addresses: [
    %Address{
      id: "123",
      type: "home"
    }
  ]
```

How can I query all people that have addresses with id = `123` and type = `home`?

EDIT: As suggested, I've tried:

```
query =
  from p in People,
  where: fragment(
    "? <@ ANY(?)",
    ~S|{"id": 123, "type":"home"}|,
    p.addresses
  )

Repo.all(query)
```

And I get this error

```
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42809 (wrong_object_type): op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side
```

EDIT: This error was due to a wrong definition of the field in the migration.
It was defined as a `map`, and according to [embeds_many documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#embeds_many/3) it should be `{:array, :map}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One might use `fragment` and internal PostgreSQL capabilities:

```
query =
  from p in People,
  where: fragment(
    "? <@ ANY(?)",
    ~S|{"id": 123, "type":"home"}|,
    p.addresses
  )

Repo.all(query)
```

Comment: This would work with a normal `has_many` relationship. But we're dealing with `embeds_many` here

Comment: Oh indeed, did not notice that. |> Updated.

Comment: I get an error. Will update the question with the information

Comment: Sounds weird since `addresses` are indeed a list (an array in PostgreSQL terminology.) This code works for me, btw; maybe the issue is induced?

Comment: Weird indeed, your code makes sense. I've cleaned my DB and added one element, and the addresses look like a list:

    [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "home"
        (...)
      }
    ]

Maybe there's something else going, I'll keep looking. Thanks for your help

Comment: I think I've found the problem: in the migration, the embedded field was defined as a map. According to [embeds_many docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#embeds_many/3), it should be defined as `{:array, :map}`. If you add this to your response, I'll gladly accept it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Indeed. With the proper definition, the above code should work AFAICT.